# compute() in dask not working

Tags: dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying a simple parallel computation in Dask.
This is my code.

```
  import time
  import dask as dask
  import dask.distributed as distributed
  import dask.dataframe as dd
  import dask.delayed as delayed
  from dask.distributed import Client,progress

  client = Client('localhost:8786')
  df = dd.read_csv('file.csv')
  ddf = df.groupby(['col1'])[['col2']].sum() 
  ddf = ddf.compute()
  print ddf
```

It seems fine from the documentation but on running I am getting this :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "dask_prg1.py", line 17, in <module>
    ddf = ddf.compute()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 156, in compute
   (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 402, in compute
   results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 2159, in get
direct=direct)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1562, in gather
asynchronous=asynchronous)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 652, in sync
return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 275, in sync
six.reraise(*error[0])
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 260, in f
result[0] = yield make_coro()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
value = future.result()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 260, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1439, in _gather
traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 122, in read_block_from_file
with lazy_file as f:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 166, in __enter__
f = SeekableFile(self.fs.open(self.path, mode=mode))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/local.py", line 58, in open
return open(self._normalize_path(path), mode=mode)
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.csv'
```

I am not understanding what is wrong.Kindly help me with this .Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to pass the absolute file path to `read_csv`. The reason is, that you are giving the work of opening and reading the file to a dask worker, and you might not have started that worked with the same working directory as your script/session.

Comment: That's not the issue .Tried it. I also tried omitting the compute() statement and then running . It runs fine .So,I think the issue is with compute() statement.

Comment: Are your workers on the same machine and do they have permission to see the same files?

Comment: Thank you. That's the issue . Workers are on different machines and probably one of them is not able to access the csv file.